# Collection of short sci-fi stories - zombie soldiers and a man tears his own heart out

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

In the title - I would've read it sometime in the mid to late 90s, I suppose. Cover just had a weird-looking humanoid alien figure, front profile (head/chest) - wish I could be more detailed.

Anyway - the two stories I remember. The first one, dead humans are able to be resurrected and fight in wars, although they are just a bit clumsier/stupider than they were when they were alive? The protagonist looks down on them, until he finds out partway through that he actually is one himself. The zombie soldiers derisively refer to human soldiers as "realo trulos", I remember that much.

The second one, all I can remember is that it involved flashbacks to the Vietnam War, and at the end, the main character tears his own heart out with his bare hands.

Answer (score 16):

Google tells me that 'Realo trulos' is used in the story 'Down Among the Dead Men' by William Tenn. With that as a starting point, I think your anthology was [Monster Brigade 3000](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?22611) - the cover is a match, and the third story, 'The Monster' by Joe Haldeman fits the recollections of Vietnam and the description of a character ripping their own heart out.

It was published in 1996, so consistent with when you remember reading it.

You can read it with (free) registration at [archive.org.](https://archive.org/details/monsterbrigade300000unse/page/n1/mode/2up)